# Turtle not working in IDLE

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm running IDLE 3.4.3 in Win7 - Python 3.4.3.

## I enter this code and save as testing.py:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
    turtle = Turtle()
  screen = Screen()
  turtle.forward(100)
```

===========================

## I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/testing.py", line 1, in 
    from turtle import Turtle, Screen
  File "C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop\turtle.py", line 6, in 
    forward(100)
NameError: name 'forward' is not defined

## >>>

I've tried all I can find on this site but still no joy. Help please.

Answer (score 3):

> File "C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop\turtle.py"

Don't name your source file `turtle.py` as that's the name of the turtle module and you end up confusing the `import` statement.  Name it something else and try again.